# MongoDB 4.0 : e-commerce Apps

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions, nosql, mongodb-java

Is it possible to use mongoDB in production for a massively scalable e-commerce app? I’m planning to build simple e-commerce store that sells clothes. Workflows include user logins, add to cart, checkout/pay. It may involve simple transactions when creating order + updating inventory count.
I wonder if rdbms like mysql is more suited for this type
of store?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo4.0 can well handle high concurrency and support transaction processing, but it is not as simple as MySQL transaction processing. You can consider the mixed use of SQL (MySQL) +NoSQL (mongo).

Comment: I was looking at the sample transaction code using mongodb 4.0, but it really looks similar to mysql transaction. What are the caveats? Maintaining 2 different database seems to add a lot of complexities.

Comment: @user1955934 from my experience maintaining 2 different databases is needed only in rare cases. Ask yourself: am I able to work with differences between sql/nosql in terms of concepts and query languages ?